# Generate urls from mongo Obj.ID for all users in DB

Tags: mongodb, url, mongoose, mean-stack, objectid

Task: Unique URL for each registered user.

Using:
Mongoose, Express, Angular 4, Node.

Desired outcome:
http://localhost:3000/user/207502j20nf23hf928n3f982

`path: 'user/:id'` Should represent Registered users profiles.

`path: 'user/**'` Should lead to 404.

Method provided by [Moshe Karmel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4138452/moshe-karmel) @ Answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you got to do.

1) Set up a route in express for user/:id
2) Check if you have a user that matches that is
3) If yes respond with the user, else respond 404

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res){
    // query mongoose to get user by if
    User.find({ _id : req.params.id }, function(err, user){
        if(user){
            // we have a user with that id
            res.status(200).json(user);
        }else{
            res.status(404).json('not found');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is it.
Thank you so so much!!  :)